# Communicate between two qt objects in different threads through slots and signals

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I want to connect two qt object that runs in different threads.(download_webm and player)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    DownloadWebm *download_webm;

    MyThread *DownloadWebm_Thread = new  MyThread(download_webm);

    DownloadWebm_Thread->start();

    LinuWebmPlayer *player = new LinuWebmPlayer(argv[1],0);

    QObject::connect(download_webm,SIGNAL(send_packege(Video_Bytes_Package)),player,SLOT(play()));

    player->show();





    return app.exec();
}
```

MyThread header file :

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H
#include <qthread.h>
#include <downloadwebm.h>
class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyThread(DownloadWebm *&we);
    MyThread();


    DownloadWebm **getWebm() const;

protected:
    DownloadWebm **webm;
    void run();
};





#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

and cpp:

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread()
{

}

DownloadWebm **MyThread::getWebm() const
{
    return webm;
}

MyThread::MyThread(DownloadWebm *&we)
{
    webm = &we;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
   *webm = new DownloadWebm("http://trilulilu.de.de/recstreamingsource?movie=3860","asd");
}
```

If I comment the QObject:: connect line from the main everything works fine, is there something I miss regarding communication between threads in qt?

......................................................

Comment: ***is there something I miss regarding communication between threads in qt?*** No using connect is supported between threads. You may want to specify `Qt::QueuedConnection` but Qt usually figures that out for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with download_webm the program sees the pointer as uninitialized so I think, but I initialized in the mythread constructor

Comment: I see the problem. There is no guarantee that the thread already started when you connect() so `download_webm` could still be uninitialized. QThread::start() does not wait till the thread is actually started.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) we can see that `connect`/`disconnect`:

> Note: These functions are also thread-safe:

and another thing that we can notice is that `connect` accepts `Qt::ConnectionType` which will tell Qt how to manage the connection.

Please see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) to avoid surprises.